# Discrepancy on Type error messages on API

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, api

According to [StackEschange Api Error Documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/error), an `error` should return the following fields:

**description**  `string`

**error_id** `integer`

**error_name** `string`

Although, the `description` field doesn't exist, only `error_message`

```
{"error_id":404,"error_message":"no method found with this
 name","error_name":"no_method"});
```

Comment: This seems consistent with the error handling page https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/error-handling

Comment: @Braiam yes, but the needs to be updated on the Api documentation.

Comment: The discussion tag was wrong but the support tag description says: **"A request for assistance with one of the site's features."**.

Comment: @PedroLobito The API is not technically part of the site. It IS "part of the software that powers the network". Personally, I think that API questions are better suited for Stack Apps, but it's not off topic here, either.

Comment: Well, for me you are not looking for assistance with the features, but a fix of the site documentation.

Comment: @Braiam I'm also trying to understand which one is correct, the api or the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is correct, but a little confusing.

Basically, that page is describing the error-type *in a specific API*: ([/errors](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/errors#filter=default&run=true)). It is entirely correct to say that this API returns a `description`, `error_id` and `error_name` for each possible error that the system chooses to advertise.

This is *completely unrelated* to the "what happens when an actual API call goes wrong" API, in which case an `error_id`, `error_message` and `error_name` are returned in the [common response wrapper](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper). While I agree that it might have been nice if the same noun had been used in each place, we can't change it now without it being a fundamentally breaking change to either one API (/errors), or every API (the common response wrapper).

I will add some words to the `/errors` documentation to minimize confusion.

Comment: Sounds great @marc, thank you for updating the documentation.